# How to remove Python 3.6 from Ubuntu?

Tags: python, uninstall

I just installed Ubuntu, and it comes with default a default Python version of 3.6.7. I installed Python 3.7.3 by following [these instructions](https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-the-latest-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/) (changing 3.7.2 to 3.7.3 as appropriate) and it all worked well.

Now I have two Python 3 versions, both working. I would now like to remove Python 3.6.7 and keep 3.7.3.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Don't remove python if you want to keep using Ubuntu. Things will break if you do, so think of plan B now.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks, but when i do `pip3 install ..` it doesn't work it just installs for python 3.6 and python 3.7 doesn't get installation

Comment: @User1984 Then why didn't you ask for that? Please read http://xyproblem.info And the solution would be to try `pip3.7`.

Comment: @Murphy i got this error when i ran `pip3.7 install requests` Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chardet'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: @Murphy this isn't xyproblem i asked because i wanted to remove version3.6, why should i keep more than one python3 version on my pc but turns out i *can't* so i referred to another solution

Comment: "why should i keep more than one python3 version on my pc" For the exact reason you were given by @mikewhatever. BTW, this would be a good time to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ubuntu* uses `python` for many system related functionalities. You must not remove the Python installation that is preinstalled by it, or you'll end up with a broken system, perhaps beyond repair.

If for some reason you need to use a more recent Python version, just install it parallel and call it explicitely, e. g. with `python3.7`, as `python3` will point to the default installation. The same goes for `pip`, [which may need the `--user` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770268/5794048) or being called with `sudo` depending on the permissions.

Comment: can you give me example of using `pip3.7` that will work i.e `pip3.7 install requests --user` ??

Answer (score 7):

I  installed python 3.7 and then:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

See what is there, normally it will be an error, then:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2

sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Choose 2 and you are done.